# What are the best sites for reference in programming for .NET development?

Tags: .net, web, reference

What are the best sites for reference in programming for .NET development? Websites on WPF would be great but if you have some on other types of technologies from .NET, I am opened to that too (just write it though).

Comment: This *really* depends on the type of development, and the kind of reference you're looking for...  eg web development references are very different than API references...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/hi-in/default.aspx)

[www.codeproject.com](http://www.codeproject.com/)

Answer (score 3):

http://www.asp.net/

https://web.archive.org/web/20211020202742/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/

Blog : http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/

Answer (score 3):

You're going to get a lot of answers pointing you to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/default.aspx) as this is the official source of .Net documentation. There are plenty of other sites out there with good information about .Net technologies, but they usually focus on a subset of .Net as .Net development is a vast subject.

If you could tell us what specific .Net technologies you're interesting in learning about, we can probably point you to more specific sources of information besides MSDN.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.asp.net/ of course